# Docker for Windows - Mount directory is coming empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-for-windows

I have an image with MYSQL installed. I need to map the /var/lib/mysql directory to my host system. Following is the screenshot that I see within that directory, when I use the following command

> docker run --rm -it --env-file=envProxy --network mynetwork --name my_db_dev -p 3306:3306 my_db /bin/bash

[image: Screenshot of the Docker container without mount from the same image]

Now when I try to mount a directory from my host ( Windows 10 ), by running another container from the same image, the mysql directory is blank.

> docker run --rm -it --env-file=envProxy --network mynetwork  -v D:/docker/data:/var/lib/mysql --name my_db_dev1 -p 3306:3306 my_db /bin/bash

Also tried this, but none works

> > docker run --rm -it --env-file=envProxy --network mynetwork  -v D:\docker\data:/var/lib/mysql --name my_db_dev1 -p 3306:3306 my_db /bin/bash

[image]

One thing that I see, is that the mysql directory in the path has now root user, instead of mysql as in the previous case.

I wanted all the content from the existing container (mysql directory ) to be copied back to the host mount directory

Is that Possible ? and How can that be achieved ?

Comment: I haven't used docker on win for a while, but can you double-check that it is still required to give docker permissions to read from the drive - there was an option for that in the user interface. See the docs here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: I have given necessary permission as required

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Docker Desktop(2.0.0.3 (31259)). I'd got the solution from [this issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/25#issuecomment-381409350).

> I ensured the containers were stopped, opened docker settings, selected "Shared Drives", removed the tick on "C" and added it again. Docker asked for the Windows account credentials and I entered the new ones. After that and starting containers, mount volumes were ok. Problem solved.

[It](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071814/6234590) could fix the problem more simply by just reset the credentials in Docker Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get files **from** container into host, better use `docker cp` command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

It will look like:
`docker cp my_db_dev1:/var/lib/mysql d:\docker\data`

### UPD

> Actually I want to persist the database files across other containers,
>   so I wanted use volumes

In this case you have to:

1. Start using `docker-compose` to orchestrate containers.
2. In `docker-compose.yml` you create volume, which is shared between all containers. Something like:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db1:
    image: whatever
  volumes:
    - myvol:/data

  db2:
    image: whatever2
  volumes:
    - myvol:/data

volumes:
  myvol:
```

Description: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: Actually I want to persist the database files across other containers, so I wanted use volumes.

Comment: Thanks, just a quick question, do volumes work properly in docker windows. ? I was trying to create volumes and assigining through docker run command, but was unable to set the source directory on host, In your above example will /data map to  /var/lib/mysql.

Comment: Yes, volumes work for Windows. But this volume **is not** mounted into host explicit path.

Comment: then in this case will myvol map to D:\docker\data and /data to /var/lib/mysql. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows paths writing with backslash '\' and it is recommended using variables to specify path. On the other side for Linux use slash '/' For example:

```
docker run -it -v %userprofile%\work\myproj\some-data:/var/data
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a folder structure like below,

C:\Users\rajit\MYSQL_DATA\MYSQL_CONFIG

C:\Users\rajit\MYSQL_DATA\DATA_DIR

then please adjust like below,

```
docker pull mysql:8.0
docker run --name mysql-docker -v C:\Users\rajit\MYSQL_DATA\MYSQL_CONFIG:/etc/mysql/conf.d --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_PASSWORD=root" --env="MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db" -v C:\Users\rajit\MYSQL_DATA\DATA_DIR:/var/lib/mysql -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score -1):

try to turn off anti virus program or fire wall. Then click on "reset credentials" under settings/shared drives.
That worked for me.

Best regards.