# Mounting a local folder in docker results in an empty directory

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

First my setup:

- windows 10 (1709  16299.967)
- wsl (ubuntu 18.04)
- docker for windows 2.0.0.2 (30215) Engine 18.09.1

I'm trying to mount a local development folder as a volume within a docker container but the mounted directory is always empty.
I have enabled the shared drive setting for c:/ through the docker for windows settings dialog.

I have tried mounting the local directory through WSL and powershell with no luck in either case. The commands I have tried are :

```
docker run -it -v /c/code/bitbucket/my-api:/var/my-api -w "/var/my-api" centos:7
docker run -it -v c:/code/bitbucket/my-api:/var/my-api -w "/var/my-api" centos:7
docker run -it -v c:\code\bitbucket\my-api:/var/my-api -w "/var/my-api" centos:7
```

In both WSL and powershell but all result in an empty /var/my-api folder

By the way if I put a folder that does not exist I get the following error:

```
➜  docker run -it -v /c/code/bitbucket/my-apizzz:/var/my-apizzz -w "/var/my-apizzz" centos:7
docker: Error response from daemon: Mount denied:
The source path "C:/code/bitbucket/my-apizzz"
doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

So I think I am using the correct syntax it's just that docker can't seem to access the file share

Comment: Check [this official issues](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/25#issuecomment-381409350) to get more detail and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this issue before. Try resetting your credentials here:

[image]

And then test with:

```sh
docker run --rm -v c:/code/bitbucket/my-api:/data alpine ls /data
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. I think i may have changed my password since i ticked the share button some weeks/months ago.